# Javascript EventSource get stuck on pending state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, react-router, server-sent-events

I am using Server-Sent Events and the Javascript EventSource API for a live React dashboard, and I have multiple tabs, each of which uses one EventSource. When I navigate between different tabs the stream of events gets stuck on pending like the last "live" stream on the screenshot below:
[image]

Because of this the data is not loaded into the React dashboard and is stuck on loading. I can see that the streams that are opened earlier despite the fact that I close them:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState(undefined);
  
  const reportDataEventSource = new EventSource(
    "http://localhost:8080/report/heatMap/live"
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    reportDataEventSource.onmessage = e => {
      setData(JSON.parse(e.data));
    };

    return () => reportDataEventSource.close()
  }, []);
```

What can be the reason for this and how can I fix this?

Comment: I never worked with `EventSource` but I would love to find a workaround for this issue. It could be very possible that since you're switching focus context (tabs), the operations are delegate to have less priority in the original tab and that might messed up, but it's a long shot… do you have a MWE that you can put online somewhere so we can test it?

Comment: is your server behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: ok deal with this all day websocket also hangs too, when implement simple ping command every 20 sec. its work as should + one when starts

Comment: ServerSideEvents (EventSource) is such a mess... I used WebSockets and it worked. Then I tried to use this one and had the same issue as you. "EventSource failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the connection ID is not present on the server, or a proxy is refusing/buffering the connection" - this is what I got in 90 sec, although should have received the event result data. And it is absotely unclear, why it does not work - server does not display any issues.

Answer (score 0):

"http://localhost:8080" indicates that you are using webpack-dev-server and since you did not set `withCredentials:true` in eventSource, that means you are allowing "*" wildcard for CORS but you have to set up CORS policy in webpack.config.js

```
 devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: { aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000 },
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
    }
  },
```

If this does not resolve the issue, set `onError` and log the error:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // this also should be inside useEffect
    reportDataEventSource.onmessage = e => {
      setData(JSON.parse(e.data));
    };

     reportDataEventSource.onerror = () => {
    // error log here 
    
    reportDataEventSource.close();
  }

    return () => reportDataEventSource.close()
  }, []);
```